# How can i segment an image using opencv4android

Tags: android, opencv

I am developing an application on the android platform. The app basically needs to capture an image using the camera, and then analyse the captured image to see where does red and blue color ends and the next step is to make a contour arround twi shape cirle and triangle.(already done ) Now i Have to move to the next step : segmentation
Can you help me how to segment this images. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by segmentation; do you mean create a bounding box around each identified shape and treat as separate image? - if you have an example image, that would help.

Comment: i have make a contour arround an object and now i would like to separate this object in an image view

Comment: Would you be ok with using Imgproc.boundingRect to determine the bounding rect for the contour and then use it to create a submat that you can then create a new image from.

Comment: ok i will try it . I wanna just ask you if you have a code who can help me ! please i need your help

Answer (score 3):

Assuming c is your contour:

```
Rect roi = Imgproc.boundingRect(c);
Mat newMat = mRgba.submat(roi);
Bitmap bmp1 = Bitmap.createBitmap(newMat.width(), newMat.height(),
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Utils.matToBitmap(newMat, bmp1);
```

bmp1 should then hold the image you want.

This will however give you a rectangular image that shows the bounding area of your original object, so if it was a circle you have detected, you will get the circle plus all the other parts of the image contained in the bounding box. If you *just* want the detected object and have the rest of the content as transparent then that is a slightly harder problem.